# Why the error indicates that Method was discovered in the .class file but cannot be resolved in the class object] with root cause?

Tags: java, illegalstateexception

When I use the marven project ,compiling the project ,the next error happens .I do not know why ,wish someone can help me resolve the problem ,thanks !

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [taotao-manager] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method [getItemList] was discovered in the .class file but cannot be resolved in the class object] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.taotao.controller.ItemController.getItemList(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$LocalVariableTableVisitor.resolveMember(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:245)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$LocalVariableTableVisitor.visitEnd(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:231)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1024)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:695)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:73)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterName(MethodParameter.java:437)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.updateNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.getNamedValueInfo(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Post your class `com.taotao.controller.ItemController` and code that calls `java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod`

Comment: Check for multiple copies (different versions) of ItemController.class on your class path. Remove extra copies.

Comment: And do a clean build.

Comment: Accept your message and just do a clean build .The problem is solved .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same today, cleaned my build & refreshed my Gradle project,
it solved the problem.
It may happen when you git pull and try to start your instance without a refresh or Gradle build.